# How to keep scroll bar position always at the top of the view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a layout in which I am using a Scrollview to put the stuff in the view. But when in the view, I moved the scrollbar down and then moved to next view, the scrollbar remained at the same position, meaning, at the bottom part of the view. I want to make sure that the scrollbar remains at the top of the view always, by default. This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="90.0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1.0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="1.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/explain_QuestionImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/explain_question"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/explain_QuestionImageView"
                    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/question_text"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/question_text1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/explain_separator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5.0dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/explain_question"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/explain_explaination"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/explain_separator"
                    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_green" />

        </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a1501e5633125fb"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 123456789ABCDEF" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_Buttons1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40.0dip"
            android:layout_above="@id/ad"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#ff777777"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/PrevExplainationButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/ibtn"
                android:onClick="onPrevExplainationButtonClick"
                android:text="Previous" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/NextExplainationButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="2.0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/ibtn"
                android:onClick="onNextExplainationButtonClick"
                android:text="Next" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please tell me how to do that.

Your question is ambiguous. If the `ScrollView` remains where you scroll after you go to the next/previous question simply use the the method `scrollTo` on the `ScrollView` like this when you switch questions:

```
((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1)).scrollTo(0, 0);
```

If you go to a new activity and want the `ScrollView` at the start position then simple place the above line in the `onResume` method of the `Activity`.